# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module

Tags: angular

I did an update from Angular 6 to Angular 8. I get this warning if I run `ng serve`:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 94814:19-45
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Soupport'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nailing the source-map-support version to 0.4.3 indeed fixes the problem.

For more details : [Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'module' in [...]source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support/issues/155)

Comment: Oke, thank you. I did a npm install source-map-support@0.4.3 and it works